# sql query to select week,month, days

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

please guys, i need an sql query to select data from an access database using vb6. the query will only provide current date and the filed been compaired is curr_date in the database.

for example

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE curr_date BETWEEN firstoflastmonth AND endoflasthmonth;

SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE curr_date BETWEEN firstoflastweek AND endoflasthweek;

SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE curr_date BETWEEN firstofthismonth AND endofthismonth;

SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE curr_date BETWEEN firstofthsiweek AND tilldate;
```

The problem i have figuring ot is how to specify the two dates in comparison

Comment: How do you define "last week" and "last month"? Next Tuesday, on March 1st, is last month February? This is not a triviality -- different users may interpret these plain-language terms differently and not get the results they are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it not easiest to just check wich month/week you want it to be in then?

From you examples:

```
SELECT *    FROM TABLE   
WHERE curr_date BETWEEN firstoflastmonth AND endoflasthmonth;
```

This would become (with the [month](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/month.php) function used)

```
SELECT *    FROM TABLE   
WHERE month(curr_date) = month(dateadd("m",-1,Date()));
```

This compares the month of your curr_date to the month of Date (the current date) minus one month, so the last month.
This can also be done using [datediff](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php):

```
SELECT *    FROM TABLE   
WHERE DateDiff ( "m", curr_date, date()) = 1
AND curr_date < date();
```

The last line is added to make sure that dates one month later are not selected.

Same thing can be applied to the other queries using the date function found [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/)

*Links used to the reference sheet provided by Richard Calahan*

Comment: The second SQL statement won't use indexes, so I'd recommend against it. Instead, I'd figure out what dates start and end the period and use those instead of expressions.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton So if I understand correctly, you would still use a solution similar to the request itself (using something like 'firstoflastmonth','endoflastmonth',...in the query) ? Then how would you recommend using that in a generic query?

Comment: The point is that you want to have a WHERE clause that tests against an indexed value in a field. So, you can use an expression, such as `BETWEEN DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1) And DateAdd("m", 1, DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),1)) - 1`. That uses expressions to calculate the values you're testing, but what you're testing against is an indexed field.

Comment: I don't want to start a discussion here, but am genuinly interested.
First of all: in your first comment, you referred to the second SQL statement. Is that about the one with the dateadd() function or the datediff() function?
I ask this is because it seems to me my example with dateadd() does compare to the indexed value (curr_date) as you proposed. 
I can however, see your comment in my last example, where I used the indexed value in the expression itself. I did not know that this would not use the indexes though.

Answer (score 2):

The Date() function will return the current timestamp. Use the ms-access date functions to work backwards/forwards from there, for example:

```
DateAdd("m",2,Date())
```

Adds two months to the current date. check [this reference](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/) out

Comment: that's true, and i know this. But it dosen't specify the begininhg and ending dates. different months end in different days, som 28, some 30, others 31.

Comment: Just to be fussy, Date() will return the current date, Now() will return the current timestamp.

Comment: Ah yes, true. The function should still work though. And btw, Yohsoog has the right idea. Instead of using the "between" clause, if all you want is a specific month or week, dont bother calculating an entire range, just make a direct "equal to" comparison.

Answer (score 1):

See:

[Why should I consider using an auxiliary calendar table?](http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html)

The article's code is specifically for SQL Server but the techniques are portable to most SQL platforms (and even MS Access :) The idea is that SQL is a declarative language and will favour a data-driven set-based solution over a calucate-procedurally-on-the-fly approach.

You'd have one row for each and every day required by your enterprise, covering a few decades will not amount to much (thousands of rows). Each of those days will have values for `firstoflastmonth`, `firstoflastweek`, etc (note sure what `tilldate` means, though); these values are generated once e.g. using a spreadsheet. You can then `JOIN` to this table using `NOW()`, Access's (ACE's, Jet's, whatever's) implementation of Standard SQL's `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Further note that because Access uses double float values to model all temporal data, `BETWEEN`s euality operation is usally unsuitable. So rather than this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE curr_date BETWEEN firstoflastmonth AND endoflasthmonth;
```

...instead use this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE (
        curr_date >= firstoflastmonth 
        AND curr_date < firstofthishmonth
       );
```

Comment: you haven't still answered my question. how do i get the dates

Comment: @Smith: same as anything in SQL: you put the values in a table and you query them. Decide what the first day of last week was for 2011-02-24 (Sunday? Monday?) and stick it in the Calendar table. Do the same for the first day of this month, first day of last month and all the rest. Then do the same for all the other days in the foreseeable future. Sure, there will be ten thousand or more but you only have to do it once. Use Excel.