# Adding an automatic date range to a query in VBA access

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is my first question, please be kind. I am writing a macro in access and I want a series of reports to run one after another. the problem is all report have a date range that needs to be entered. Some are for the previous week some are for the previous month.

Is there a way in VBA or the macro creator to automatically calculate a date range for the previous month or week and populate the field to fully automate the process without manually entering the date range each time.

I am a new to VBA. Any help would be great, just point me in the right direction.  Have a good day.

Comment: This answer has some solutions [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101656/sql-query-to-select-week-month-days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query is created using the query design window in MS Access and then cut from SQL view. It will show records for last week, where ww is week number, in table1

```
SELECT Table1.AKey, Table1.atext, Table1.ADate, 
       Format([ADate],"ww") AS Week, Month([ADate]) AS [Month], 
       Year([ADate]) AS [Year]
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Format([ADate],"ww"))=Format(Date(),"ww")-1)
AND ((Year([ADate]))=Year(Date())));
```

You will notice that one column is called Month. You can use this to set a previous month in a similar way to setting the previous week. For example, both last week and last month:

```
SELECT Table1.AKey, Table1.atext, Table1.ADate, 
       Format([ADate],"ww") AS Week, Month([ADate]) AS [Month], 
       Year([ADate]) AS [Year]
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Format([ADate],"ww"))=Format(Date(),"ww")-1) 
AND ((Year([ADate]))=Year(Date()))) 
OR (((Month([ADate]))=Month(Date())-1) 
AND ((Year([ADate]))=Year(Date())));
```

The SQL could be written much more neatly, but you may as well start with the query design window.

Answer (score 0):

i guess the date has a own field in the database you open
then you can do something like this

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE Date >= " & now() -7
rs.open(strSQL)
' for the last week

strSQL = "Select * FROM reports WHERE Date >= " & now() - 30
rs.open(strSQL)
' for the last month
```

but you will need to format now() to the same format as it is in your Table
and that is just kinda the rawest code. i had to handle something similar and this worked out quite well

Comment: If today is August 31st, Now-30 is 1st August.

Comment: yes i know ;) but i was not sure about the Date[mm] format and this works for not-too careful people too. also 30 days is the normal definition for a month in business